# Accessing this.props.location from a Header component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

As you know, `this.props.location` is only accessible if the component being rendered is wrapped inside `<Route />`.

Rather than tracking and saving the URL of a user navigation by putting a `this.props.location` in every component that I have, I want to pull the location by putting only one `this.props.location` at the Header. However, the Header is not wrapped by `<Route />` for obvious reasons below.

What is the best way to get access to `this.props.location` from a Header component whose route tree is defined as follows:

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Route path="/dummy" component={Dummy} />
        </div>
      </Router>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem,

**First,** have a default Route that renders Header like

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route component={Header} />
          <Route path="/dummy" component={Dummy} />
        </div>
      </Router>
...
```

**Second:** make use of `withRouter` in your `Header` component

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router;
...
export default withRouter(Header);
```